# Issue opening new Mac Terminal with arguments to run Mongo shell

Tags: mongodb, bash, macos

I'm trying to start a new Terminal app with arguments to start mongo and connect to my local database. It opens a new Terminal but doesn't run my argument. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
open /Application/Utilities/Termminal.app/Contents/MacOS/Terminal --args ./Users/donny/Downloads/mongo/mongo mongodb://localhost:27021
```

Comment: @hmedia1 Even the AppleScript approach? Are you sure? See the updated duplicate now.

Comment: @tripleee there's caveats on all of these approaches and in some cases special security allowances required

Comment: So do you have a better answer or is the answer just "it cannot be done properly and here are my caveats on the existing answers"? The latter may well be suitable as a new answer on the duplicate.

Comment: @tripleee might be a thin line ... but since there's a proper way it would be good to address it.  I've seen (and viewed) many iterations of this question now

Comment: Okay, reopened; please go ahead and answer. Thanks!

Comment: @DonnyV. I'm afraid I am getting different results on different versions of OS X.  It works perfectly on my development machine.  This has been revealing for me also.  I've removed my answer to avoid confusion.  Glad you found the solution none the less

Comment: @hmedia1 Thanks for trying anyway!